# Passing FormData as parameter to a post request using axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, axios

I'm trying to upload an employee by filling a form with some strings and a picture, I'm using axios, node.js to do it, but when I hit the submit button I get an error (500):

> message   Employees validation failed: description: fill the employee's
>   description, name: fill the employee's name.

but I'm 100% sure that the form was filled correctly and I don't have a clue why I'm getting this internal server error.

```
export const createEmployee = async (formData) => {
    try {
      const url = `${Constants.BASE_URL}/employee`
      const res = await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url,
        data:formData,
        headers: {
        "Content-Type": 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      });

      if (res.data.status === 'success') {
        showAlert('success', `${res.data.name} Cadastro realizado com sucesso!`);
        window.location = '/employee';
      }
    } catch (err) {
      showAlert('error', err.response.data.message);
    }
  };
```

**Submit:**

```
const employeeCreateDataForm = document.querySelector('#createEmployeeForm');
if (employeeCreateDataForm)
  employeeCreateDataForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append('name', document.getElementById('name').value);
    form.append('photo', document.getElementById('photo').files[0]);
    form.append('phone', document.getElementById('phone').value);
    form.append('description', document.getElementById('description').value);

    createEmployee(form);
});
```

Comment: You didn't set your `formData` to the correct property in your request, it should be `data:formData` not just `formData` as that will be equivalent to `formData:formData` which axios doesn't use

Comment: @PatrickEvans now it is set as you mention, but it gives me the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the header of `"Content-Type": 'multipart/form-data'` and pass the `formData` in `data`.

**Example:**

```
export const createEmployee = async (formData) => {
  try {
    const url = `${Constants.BASE_URL}/employee`
    const res = await axios({
      method: 'post',
      url,
      data: formData,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    });
    if (res.data.status === 'success') {
      showAlert('success', `${res.data.name} Cadastro realizado com sucesso!`);
      window.location = '/employee';
    }
  } catch (err) {
    showAlert('error', err.response.data.message);
  }
};
```

On backend side, To handle the  `multipart/form-data` you need a body parser (such as multer).

Yon can read more about this [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer). But you could use some other parser as well.

**NodeJS Example:**

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const multer  = require('multer');

const app = express();
const upload = multer();

app.use(cors());
app.post("/employee", upload.single('photo'), (req, res) => {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
});
app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port 5000`);
});
```

Comment: You need to add a body parser at backend. (such as multer).